# Python - safely close socket connection on terminal from keyboard input besides cntrl-c?

Tags: python, sockets, python-sockets

The server I'm communicating to has stream session slots and sometimes the stream session couldn’t opened because all stream session slots are used. I suspect its because I'm building a program that talks to the server and feel when I cntrl-c to force stop the stream it doesn't close safely keeping the stream session slot open for that instance connection on the server. So when I terminate the program dozens of times this error builds up

I don't have much knowledge on Python Networking to know if cntrl-c is as clean as hitting a key and calling the method close_conn(sock) but I want to try.

Suppose I'm running this on my terminal"

```
 ...
    print("Now listening from server for data...\n")
      while True:

        received = sock.recv(1024) 

        #pseudo_code
        if (user_input == "e") close_conn(sock)
```

How can for debugging purposes close the connection safely?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to close your socket when you press "Ctrl + C" and then wait for another connection, you can try the code below.

```
while True:
    try:
        received = sock.recv(1024)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print "i want to close client socket"
        sock.close()
        break
    except socket.error, e:
        print "a socket erro has occured, e = ", e
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

After re-reading your question I think I answered some other question. Sorry.

I don't know whether you identified root of problem correctly, but you can put your code in `try...except...finally...` structure. You can omit `except` or `finally`, if you don't need one of them.

for example:

```
from time import sleep
try:
    sleep(10)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print "This line is printed only if Ctrl+C was pressed"
finally:
    print "This line is printed even if Ctrl+C was pressed"
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the code you gave since you said

> "You want to try `...given code...`"

. You are almost there, just need an extra line. see below.

```
...
print("Now listening from server for data...\n")
while True:

    received = sock.recv(1024)  

    # code
    if user_input == "e":
        break #breaks out of while loop and calls close_conn(sock)
close_conn(sock)
```

From your code, am assuming the `close_conn(sock)` is a function that calls the `sock.close()`, `user_input` is a variable that when it is equal to `"e"`, it breaks the loop to close the socket.